# Magento 2 (EE) : Custom theme is not fully working

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise

I have created a custom theme and activate that theme from admin. The custom theme is not fully loaded on the frontend. In custom theme, we have overridden many core theme modules template files.I have set one parent theme which is also a custom theme.

I have done following steps to resolve this issue but the issue still persists.

1. set the custom theme from admin
2. `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
4. `bin/magento  indexer:reindex`

Note: some of templates files has overridden.

Magento version 2.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issue by changing the theme `type` from `virtual` to `physical` in theme table.

and then run following commands:

1. `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
2. `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. `bin/magento cache:flush`

Answer (score 1):

Try to the below step:

1. remove var/cache, var/generation , var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed, var/di (if any);
2. remove pub/static/_requirejs, pub/static/adminhtml, pub/static/frontend,
3. bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy,
4. bin/magento setup:upgrade
5. bin/magento cache:flush
6. bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: I already did that but it is not working.

Comment: did you tried the order that I have given?

Comment: Yes. But I think `bin/magento setup:clean` command is not exist.

Comment: sorry typo mistakes. I have edited.

Comment: Is there anything to do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: check from where the actual files are coming by enabling template path hint.

Comment: What things, I have to check ?

Comment: check theme is applied or not.

Comment: It's applied, Some of the files are loading from custom theme and rests are from vendor.

Comment: give the foldar name in the theme for the file which not coming from theme.